# Meaning of 'pelted clover' and 'gorged pastures' in Louise Glück poem?

Tags: meaning, poetry, louise-gluck

What do 'pelted clover' and 'gorged pastures' mean in the following poem by Louise Glück? Clover leaves that are being thrown? A pasture land with a pathway in the middle?

> [**Labor Day**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=rncNEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&lpg=PT24&dq=%22pelted+clover%22&source=bl&ots=HB4BL9grX9&sig=ACfU3U02ix4S-dR8Wjb7jG5LaDzSBiQG4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicr6vV_7T4AhWDTWwGHaohAkcQ6AF6BAgcEAM#v=onepage&q=%22pelted%20clover%22&f=false)
>
> Requiring something lovely on his arm
> Took me to Stamford, Connecticut, a quasi-farm,
> His family's; later picking up the mammoth
> Girlfriend of Charlie, meanwhile trying to pawn me off
> On some third guy also up for the weekend.
> But Saturday we still were paired; spent
> It sprawled across that sprawling acreage
> Until the grass grew limp
> with damp. Like me. Johnston-baby, I can still see
> The **pelted clover**, burrs' prickle fur and **gorged**
> **Pastures** spewing infinite tiny bells. You pimp.

**gorge**:

> A gorge is a deep, narrow valley with very steep sides, usually where a river passes through mountains or an area of hard rock
>
> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gorge))

> : a narrow passage through land
> *especially* : a narrow steep-walled canyon or part of a canyon
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gorge))

**pelt**:

> noun (1)
> **1**. a usually undressed skin with its hair, wool, or fur
>
> [...]
>
> verb (2)
> *transitive verb*
> **2**. HURL, THROW
> *// pelted snowballs at them*
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pelt))

Comment: Just a guess, but ***pelted clover*** may allude to ***pelta*** (shield), Which may or may not be the reference in [***Clover Pelt Giclée** fine art archival print*.](https://www.etsy.com/listing/851952150/clover-pelt-giclee-fine-art-archival)

Answer (score 3):

(Some of this answer was originally covered in comments which have since been removed.)

A “pelt” is a “hide or skin of an animal with the wool, hair, etc., still on it” (*OED*) so in context “pelted” means “having a texture resembling a pelt”, referring to the furry texture of clover flowers, which are made up of many tightly packed florets. (Noted by [aparente001](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/590565/timeline#comment_1482854) and [Stuart F](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/590565/timeline#comment_1482859).)

“Gorged” means “stuffed, crammed full”, usually with food, but here with “infinite tiny bells”, presumably meadow-plants with bell-shaped flowers such as *Campanula*, the “bellflower”.

The passage is full of sexual suggestiveness: the “grass grew limp with damp”, like lovers after intercourse (the speaker says “Like me”); “pelted” and “fur” suggest pubic hair; “prickle” suggests “prick”; “gorged” suggests “engorged”; and “pastures spewing infinite tiny bells” suggests an ejaculation. ([Noted by Zan700](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/590565/timeline#comment_1482909).)

Contra Zan700, I don’t think the speaker’s boyfriend succeeded in hooking her up with “some third guy”, as the wording is “*trying* to pawn me off” which has the implication that he failed to do so, and the speaker says that on “Saturday we still were paired”. So we have to understand the “You pimp” at the end in some other way, for example, perhaps the speaker feels as if she had been metaphorically pimped to the “gorged pastures”, which loom larger in her memory than “Johnston-baby” does.

Comment: Wouldn't just trying to pawn her off make him an (unsuccessful) pimp?

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, in a sense, but not (I think) in a strong enough sense to justify putting "You pimp" in such a significant position in the poem.

Comment: I'm inclined to disagree ... my impression is that the poem reads like she wasn't that offended at the time, but then later realized that he was a complete jerk.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of the verb sprawling in "Sprawling acreage", and where the lovers lay "sprawled", refer to some sort of disorientation in the whole act of intimacy there. If "pelted", here, is taken as a verb, then it adds to the untidiness of the place; the clover leaves being thrown about. Additionally, the reference to "burr", which is a plant that causes irritation if attached to the body, contributes to the turbulence that characterizes the connection of the lovers. So I guess the reference in the last line must be to the boyfriend itself, whom she despises for his act of trying to "pawn her off", although they continue to remain in this strained relationship.

Comment: Please explain the specific phrases in the question instead of generalized passage meaning.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Your interpretation may be correct, I haven't checked, but the question is really about the meaning of specific phrases in the poem. Could you please edit your answer to explain the meaning of these phrases? If you can then connect those meanings to your interpretation, your answer should be fine. (If there is no connection, by contrast, it would be best to remove the irrelevant parts from your answer.)

Comment: Hello, thank you and thanks for the suggestion. I have made some changes in the response with specific reference to the question. Again this is just what I thought about the poem, an observation based on the possible meanings of the terms. :)